# Getting text in nested html tag using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to print the first ten entries of a website which has a list, and I want the result in the console itself. Here's the structure of the HTML it's using

```
<div class=classname>
  <b>The text i want</b>
</div>
```

here's what i tried running in the console:

```
list = document.getElementsByClassName('classname')
for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
{
  console.log (list[i])
}
```

I am at a loss of what to do next. I'm fairly new to javascript so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `console.log (list[i].textContent)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `innerText` property to get the text.

Also, use `list.length` based comparison for running the for loop instead of arbitrary numbers such as `10` : `for(var i=0;i<10;i++)`.

```js
list = document.getElementsByClassName('classname')
for(var i=0;i < list.length;i++)
{
  console.log(list[i].innerText);
}
```

```html
<div class="classname">
  <b>The text i want</b>
</div>
```

Keep in mind that unlike `textConten`,  `innerText` will not display any text that is not visible on screen, or text inside `<script>` tags. [See this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) for more info on the differences.

Answer (score 0):

Use `textContent` or `innerText` to get the text you want. `list[i].textContent`

You can also use `.innerHTML` this will also show you tags.

**Demo**

```js
list = document.getElementsByClassName('classname')
for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++)
{
  console.log (list[i].textContent)
}
```

```html
<div class=classname>
  <b>The text i want</b>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing is you need to use [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) to get the text content inside the selected element node.

Also to make it simpler to target nested elements in JavaScript, you can use these functions:

[querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

[querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

```js
var myTags = document.querySelectorAll(".classname b");

for( var i = 0; i < myTags.length; i++ ){
  var curTag = myTags[i];
  console.log( curTag.textContent );
}
```

```html
<div class=classname>
  <b>The text i want</b>
</div>

<div class=classname>
  <b>The text i want (2nd time)</b>
</div>

<div class=classname>
  <b>The text i want (3rd time)</b>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

with jQuery, it's simple:

```
$('.classname').each(function(i,e) {
    if (i==10) return false;
    console.log($(e).text());
});
```

```js
$('.classname').each(function(i,e) {
    if (i==10) return false;
    console.log($(e).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=classname>
  <b>The text i want 1</b>
</div>
<div class=classname>
  <b>The text i want 2</b>
</div>
<div class=classname>
  <b>The text i want 3</b>
</div>
<div class=classname>
  <b>The text i want 4</b>
</div>
<div class=classname>
  <b>The text i want 5</b>
</div>
<div class=classname>
  <b>The text i want 6</b>
</div>
<div class=classname>
  <b>The text i want 7</b>
</div>
<div class=classname>
  <b>The text i want 8</b>
</div>
<div class=classname>
  <b>The text i want 9</b>
</div>
<div class=classname>
  <b>The text i want 10</b>
</div>
<div class=classname>
  <b>The text i want 11</b>
</div>
<div class=classname>
  <b>The text i want 12</b>
</div>
```